# Is there any pre built function in Java to remove special characters for SQL?

Tags: java, sql

I'm adding huge data to tables (20-50k rows).
Sometimes there are special characters gets added to table, sometimes code throws exception.
Also, while retrieving the data, special characters makes data non usable.
Can anyone let me know that is there java function to filter the these sql special character before adding to table?

FYI, i just want to remove those special characters which causes issue while inserting or fetching data from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of characters that you do not want in the database, and then check the strings you are passing in.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello W@rld?!";
        char[] charSearch = {'@','?'}; 
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
        {
            char chr = str.charAt(i);
            for(int j=0; j<charSearch.length; j++)
            {
                if(charSearch[j] == chr)
                {
                    System.out.println("Char Value "+charSearch[j]+" is present in "+str);      
                    //do whatever
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis, but i know the approach. But not 100% sure which special characters makes issue in SQL and which don't. Can you let me know the all special characters which should not be in the sql queries or data?

Comment: in large queries this will take a lot of time to search, it's better to use the built in method `String.indexOf` this will return -1 if the string doesn't have the specified char. With this you use just 1 for loop to iterate over the char array.

Comment: Nice Marcio thanks for the insight! ! “” SPACE # $ % & ‘ ( ) * + , – . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ ` { | } ~ I believe all of these should be avoided, may be more to avoid sql injection ?

Comment: Thanks Lewis and Marcio